# Use Java exceptions internally for REST API user errors?

Tags: api, null, exception

We have a REST API that works great. We're refactoring and deciding how to internally handle errors by the users of our API.

For example the user needs to specify the "movie" url parameter which should take the value of "1984", "Crash", or "Avatar". First we check to see if it has a valid value.

What would be the best approach if the movie parameter is invalid?

- return null from one of the internal methods and check for the null in the main API call method
- throw an exception from the internal method and catch exceptions in the main API method

I think it would make our code more readable and elegant to use exceptions.  However, we're reluctant because we'd be potentially throwing many exceptions because of user API input errors, our code could be perfect.  This doesn't seem to be the proper use of exceptions.  If there are heavy performance penalties with exceptions, which would make sense with stack traces needing to be collected, etc., then we're unnecessarily spending resources when all we need to do is tell the user the parameter is wrong.

These are REST API methods, so we're not propogating the exceptions to the users of the API, nor would we want to even if possible.

So what's the best practice here?  Use ugly nulls or use java's exception mechanism?

Comment: When the user passes in a movie parameter that "is invalid", does this represent a mistake the user has made, or is it just a search miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

The key is that passing a bad parameter isn't that exceptional a condition.  Exceptions are thrown for exceptional circumstances.  (That's the reason to not use them here, not the performance.)

You should be using something like Spring's DataValidation API for binding parameters that are passed in.

A client of a REST API should not be receiving null or exceptions.  They should get an error message that gives them an idea of what's going on without exposing those details.  "Sorry, we couldn't find that movie" or null?  Go with the first, hands down.

Comment: Exactly.  The RESTful API should be validating user input just like any other application.  If the input is bad, tell the user why.  If bad input makes it past your filters/validation, then that is the appropriate time to throw an exception, log it, and notify the development team so they can fix the validation (or whatever is buggy).

Answer (score 1):

If a invalid request came in (e.g. validation error) you should show 400 status code (bad request).

Internally I would also create an exception hierachy which maps to the HTTP Rest domain (see status codes for error cases).

Examples (simplified and being unchecked exceptions):

```
class RESTBaseException extends RuntimeException{
  int statusCode;

  public RESTBaseException(int statusCode){ this.statusCode=statusCode; }

  //if no statusCode passed we fallback to very broad 500 server error.
  public RESTBaseException(){ this.statusCode=500; }  
}

class RESTValidationException extends RESTBaseException{

   RESTValidationException(){
      super(404);
   }
}
```

you can extend above examples by also passing error messages to constructor to make client even more happy.

Later on you should catch these exceptions with a dedicated exception handler in your servlet handler chain (mapping status code to servlet response). For instance in spring mvc there are nice exception-handling solutions for that.

Usually I don't like to create a deep custom exception hierachies but I think for REST api layers they are OK (because the status codes are propagated later).

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are doing input validation here and in this case, your database will do a query for a safe string and it won't find the record since it don't exist in your database, ok?

If you are using any MVC framework the Model should throw already a RecordNotFound exception no?

If you are always expecting to find a value then throw the exception if it is missing. The exception would mean that there was a problem.

If the value can be missing or present and both are valid for the application logic then return a null.

More important: What do you do  in other places of the code? Consistency is important.